# Javascript, scroll event listener doesn't fire until scroll is done on mobile

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, mobile, scroll

I am using an event listener for scroll that will change a button from `position:fixed` to `position:relative` on the page depending where the user is on the page. I have a pretty straight forward setup, I am using react, when the react component mounts, I add a listener with a throttler for the scroll event. This works great on desktop, however on mobile, I notice the event to change the positioning on the element is not firing until the scroll is done.

Here is the setup I have -

On the component mount, add listener :

```
 componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', this.scrollThrottler);
  }
```

Which calls the throttling function :

```
  let scrollTimeout;
  scrollThrottler() {
    // pass through throttle designated at 15 fps
    if ( !scrollTimeout ) {
      scrollTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
        scrollTimeout = null;
        this.handleScroll();
      }, 66);
    }
  }
```

And then the function it calls just checks if a certain div at the right point on the DOM to change the class on it like so :

```
 handleScroll() {
    const width = this.state.windowWidth ? this.state.windowWidth : window.innerWidth;
    const stickyBoundary = this.refs.approved.getBoundingClientRect().top + this.refs.approved.offsetHeight + this.refs.stickyBar.offsetHeight - window.innerHeight;

    if ( (width <= 991) && (stickyBoundary > 0)) {
      this.refs.rootNode.className = 'row primary-product-block sticky-add-btn';
    } else {
      this.refs.rootNode.className = 'row primary-product-block';
    }

}
```

So this works great on desktop, however on mobile it looks like it is not snapping into position fixed or relative until after the scroll event is done. Is there anyway to smooth this out? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

add touchmove event to your code

```
componentDidMount() {
   window.addEventListener('scroll', this.scrollThrottler);
   window.addEventListener('touchmove', this.scrollThrottler);
}
```

Comment: Will this not fire both scroll and touch move though?

Comment: Is it also a good idea to removeEventListener on componentWillUnmount?

Comment: @RJM yes, i am doing that, I just did not show for this example.